# What the subgraph chromatic numbers can be?

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

Let G be graph with chromatic numnber ch(G). What are possible chromatic numbers of subgraphs G-v of G?

Such results could help to prove or reject the following conjecture: if the chromatic number of all subgraphs G-v of graph G is 2, then the chromatic number of graph G is 2 as well. I.e. property that chromatic number of graph is 2, is the recognizable property (in the sense of reconstruction conjecture). One can assume that the reverse is true - i.e. the chromatic number of G is 3 or bigger. How one can arrive at contradiction with the premise that the chromatic number of subgraphs G-v is 2 or less.

In essence this is about bipartiteness being the recognizable property.

Comment: The conjecture is false as can be seen by considering an odd cycle.

Comment: Conjecture about chromatic number 2 can be false, but conjecture about bipartiteness can be true, because reconstruction conjecture required that from property A of subgraphs G-v follows property B. Properties A and B can be different, property A should not neccesarily be bipartiteness.

Comment: I really don't understand your comments about properties and reconstruction, but I wanted to point out that it is easy to prove that the odd cycles are the _only_ counterexamples to your 2-colourable conjecture: if for every $v$ of $G$ we have $\chi(G-v) = 2$ but $\chi(G) = 3$, then $G$ must be a cycle of odd length. Don't know it that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we take the disjoint union $G \cup G$ of any graph $G$, it has $\chi(G \cup G)=\chi(G)$, so there are graphs for which deleting any vertex doesn't change the chromatic number.  There are also graphs, like cycles and complete graphs, in which deleting any vertex drops the chromatic number by one.

And no graph $G$ has the property $\chi(G-v) \leq \chi(G)-2$ because then we could take a $(\chi(G)-2)$-coloring of $G-v$ and use it to find a $(\chi(G)-1)$-coloring of $G$, which is a contradiction.

So the possible chromatic numbers of $\chi(G-v)$ are $\chi(G)$ or $\chi(G)-1$.